# Correct usage of ATL CComSafeArray when called from VB6 via OLE automation?

Tags: c++, com, vb6, atl, ole

I'm currently debugging some legacy ATL/C++ code which is called
from Visual Basic 6 to find possible memory/resource leaks.

The function called receives an array by reference:

```
STDMETHODIMP Process::Evaluate(
    IDispatch** pVBColl,
    SAFEARRAY** pResults,
    VARIANT_BOOL* pRetVal)
```

The corresponding IDL:

```
interface IProcess: IDispatch{
    [id(1337)] HRESULT Evaluate(
        [in,out] IDispatch** pVBColl,
        [in,out] SAFEARRAY(FLOAT)* pResults,
        [out,retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pRetVal);
    );
```

Now I've found three different solutions how to access and modify the
results array and return values:

**1st Solution:**

```
CComSafeArray<FLOAT>& arrResults = reinterpret_cast<CComSafeArray<FLOAT>&>(*pResults);
arrResults[1] = 3.14;
```

**2nd solution:**

```
CComSafeArray<FLOAT> arrResults = *pResults;
arrResults[1] = 3.14;
*pResults = arrResults.Detach();
```

**3rd solution:**

```
CComSafeArray<FLOAT> arrResults;
arrResults.Attach(*pResults);
arrResults[1] = 3.14;
*pResults = arrResults.Detach();
```

**Now the big question: Which one is correct?**
Which one doesn't leak?
Which is the correct way to Attach/Detach/AddRef/Release array passed by reference from VB to ATL/C++?

Attention: The arrays are declared [in,out] which cannot be changed.

Comment: Attach/Detach are exactly made for that (in fact they just copy pointers): attach to a VARIANT you don't initially own, and detach from a VARIANT you give someone else ownership. Maybe the other work (I'm unsure and I don't bother), but the intent is not clear (and you need to go in the source see how things could be overloaded)